# How can I set div position on the far right?

Tags: html, css

Demo and my code is like this :

https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/00z7vdLL/

I want to set this :

```
<div style="width: 80mm;"> 
    <table>
        <tr style="padding-right:35px">
            <td>Attachment</td>
            <td align="right">Latter Fans 023/PT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Number</td>
            <td align="right">B / 123 / I / 2016</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date</td>
            <td align="right">12 May 2017</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

on the far right

I try some step, but it does not work

How can I solve it?

Note : 
Don't use flex

Answer (score 1):

You can use css property i.e. **float: right**. This property sets the element i.e div floats to  the right.

e.g

```
<style>
       .**far-right** {
        width: 300px;
        **float: right;**
        }
     </style>
```

Content

Answer (score 0):

depending on how you want it aligned i prefer you using `p align` function..  and all you commenting here forgot to give him the `clear:left` in the wrapper css.  use a p alignment... its way better